# Recursive regex with negative lookahead

Tags: regex, perl, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to combine recursive regex with negative lookahead because my "parentheses" are longer than 1 character. I wrote following regex to prove my understanding, but it doesn't behave as expected. Is it possible to rewrite to regex the string?

```
> echo beginmbeginmmend | perl -pe 's/^begin(?:(.+)(?!egin)|(?R))*end$/well/sg'
well
```

I didn't expect that the pattern would match "beginmbeginmmend".

Meanwhile the correct regex should still match "begin_deep_begin_deepest_end_deep_end".

Comment: Please explain why you didn't expect that regex to match "beginmbeginmmend". Which rule do you have in mind for matching or not matching?

Comment: `(&R)` recurses your pattern from the beginning of your regex. How can you recurse something from the beginning twice `^begin` ? Since `^` specifies the BOS. Maybe I don't see a mystery multi-line option in the perl directive. Since I can't get past that, I can't give you a good regex.

Comment: The accepted regex won't match `begin_deep_begin_deepest_endend``. This is not a good sign and have never seen where _other text_ is required between delimiters in balanced text. Never seen it and don't believe it should be relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some issues:

- With `(.+)(?!egin)` you don't prevent that "begin" is captured there. The negative look ahead assertion comes too late. It should be asserted at *every* position, so inside that (first) capture group: `((?!begin).)+`
- With `(.+)(?!egin)` you don't prevent that "end" is captured. Yet you should, as otherwise it would allow more "end" to occur than "begin".
- In case recursion is needed, the regex doesn't allow any characters after "begin" to come *before* the recursion kicks in. Instead of either-or you need the additional characters to be allowed anyhow -- whether recursion will follow or not.
- In case recursion occurs, there is no provision to allow other characters to follow before "end" is encountered
- The `(?R)` will never match, because it will need to be at the start of a line with the `^` anchor. You need to recur the pattern that does not include those anchors. You could create a capture group that has everything except those anchors, and recur on that with `(?1)`.

Here is a correction:

```
^(begin(?:(?!end|begin).)+(?:(?1)(?:(?!end|begin).)+)*end)$
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/JW1064/1)